# iOS notification issue

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I reset my all my settings on my iPhone and it messed up my notifications.

The problem is when I tap on my notification it slides to the left and makes me tap the open button. Before I could just tap on the notification itself once and it'd open right away.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Your question is difficult to understand. It's one long sentence and I can't tell what the actual problem you're facing. Can you add screenshots and a better explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Your device must be unlocked (Face ID, Touch ID) for the notification to open immediately upon a direct touch. Otherwise, the notification will only let you slide to the left.